# Nested read statement leads to infinite loop in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, read

I'm trying to read a list of files from a command and ask the user for input for each file. I'm using one `read` to read the filenames, and another one to get user input, however this script seems to enter an infinite loop.

```
foo () {
echo "a\nb\nc" | while read conflicted_file;
do
    echo $conflicted_file
    while true; do
        read -e -p ">  " yn
        case $yn in
            [nN]* ) echo "success"; break;;
            [yY]* ) echo "fail"; break;;
            * ) echo "invalid input";;
        esac
    done
done;
}

foo
```

Removing the outer `while read` seems to resolve the issue. Any ideas why?

Comment: `read` reads from standard input, so here from the pipe.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is there a way to tell it to read from the "original" standard input and not from the pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` reads from stdin, so both of those `read`s there will read from the output of `echo` via that same pipe open on their stdin.

For the `read` inside the loop to read from the stdin outside the pipe, you could do:

```
foo () {
  printf 'a\nb\nc\n' |
    while IFS= read -r conflicted_file; do
      printf '%s\n' "$conflicted_file"
      while true; do
        IFS= read <&3 -re -p ">  " yn
        case $yn in
            [nN]* ) echo "success"; break;;
            [yY]* ) echo "fail"; break;;
            * ) echo "invalid input";;
        esac
      done
    done
} 3<&0
```

That is have it duplicated on fd 3 for the whole body of the `foo` function.

Answer (score 2):

The ‘read’ operation is trying to read from the pipe instead of the tty.  There are a couple solutions to this.

1. Run `read ... </dev/tty`.  This works as long as your foo() function isn’t ever expected to have redirected input.
2. Redirect the pipe to another file descriptor and loop around reading that so the inner read call is unaffected.

   Something like:

   ```
   exec 3< <(echo "a\nb\nc")

   while read -u 3 conflicted_file; do
      ...
      read -e -p  ">  " yn
      ...
   done

   exec 3>&-
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind giving an example of how one can achieve 2?

Comment: @Panayiotis updated the answer